# Why is ${x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ the same as $\sqrt x $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Why is ${x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ the same as $\sqrt x $?

I'm currently studying indices/exponents, and this is a law that I was told to accept without much proof or explanation, could someone explain the reasoning behind this.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you define $x^{\frac12}$? As $\exp(\frac12\ln x)$?

Comment: You would have to tell us how you define $x^{\frac12}$, but you will probably have $\left(x^{\frac12}\right)^2=x^1=x$.

Comment: [Here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65402.html) is a wonderful explanation of what you're looking for..

Comment: Hmm I think I tagged this wrong, it's more to do with the law of exponents, but as I was studying exponential functions this popped into my head.

Comment: The "exponential function" referred to by the tag is the function I mentioned in my answer that takes $x$ to $e^x$. It's not really appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

When $m$ and $n$ are integers, we have the important law that $$x^m\cdot x^n =x^{m+n}$$

We'd like this law to continue to hold when we define $x^\alpha$ for fractional $\alpha$, unless there's a good reason it shouldn't.  If we do want it to continue to hold for fractional exponents, then whatever we decide that $x^{1/2}$ should mean, it should obey the same law: $$x^{1/2}\cdot x^{1/2} = x^{1/2+1/2} = x^1 = x$$

and so $x^{1/2} = \sqrt x$ is the only choice.

Similarly, what should $x^0$ mean?  If we want the law to continue to hold, we need $$x^0\cdot x^n = x^{0+n} = x^n$$ and thus the only consistent choice is  $x^0 = 1$.  And again, why does $x^{-1} = \frac1x$? Because that's again the only choice that preserves the multiplication law, since we need $x^{-1}\cdot x^{1} = x^{-1+1} = x^0 = 1$.

---

But there is more to it than that.  Further mathematical developments, which you may not have seen yet, confirm these choices.  For example, one shows in analysis that as one adds more and more terms of the infinite sum $$1 + x + \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}6 + \frac{x^4}{24} + \cdots$$ the sum more and more closely approaches the value $e^x$, where $e$ is a certain important constant, approximately $2.71828$.  One can easily check numerically that this holds for various integer values of $x$.  For example, when $x=1$, and taking only the first five terms, we get $$1 + 1 + \frac12 + \frac16 + \frac1{24}$$

which is already $2.708$, quite close to $e^1$, and the remaining terms make up the difference.  One can calculate $e^2$ by this method and also by straightforward multiplication of $2.71828\cdot2.71828$ and get the same answer.

But we can see just by inspection that taking $x=0$ in this formula gives $e^0 = 1$ because all the terms vanish except the first.  And similarly, if we put in $x=\frac12$ we get approximately $1.648$, which is in fact the value of $\sqrt e$.

If it *didn't* work out this way, we would suspect that something was wrong somewhere.  And in fact it has often happened that mathematicians have tried defining something one way, and then later developments revealed that the definition was not the right one, and it had to be revised.  Here, though, that did not happen.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you!

Comment: Can I give you some more points somehow?

Comment: Your thanks are my reward.

Comment: @Assad: One of the choices when [starting a bounty](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) is "reward a good answer."  You must wait 2 days before you can start a bounty, however.

Comment: We might think it's equally sensible to define the special case $0^0$ as $0$, but the mathematical convention for that is indeed $0^0 = 1$ in accord with the explanation above.

Comment: I thought I'd throw in an example of a case where a definition had to be revised in light of later developments. To find the transpose of a matrix, we simply reflect it across the main diagonal: $(a^T)_{ij} = a_{ji}$. Except no, that's actually wrong. It *happens* to work, if all the $a_{ij}$ are real. The correct definition has $(a^T)_{ij} = \overline{a_{ji}}$, the complex conjugate of $a_{ji}$. For matrices with real entries, it happens that $a_{ij} = \overline{a_{ij}}$, but when you move to complex matrices it becomes apparent that there was a conjugation operation in there all along.

Comment: Very nice answer Sir. +1! For the reason why $x^0=1$, I explain it like this to my friends.
\begin{align}
\frac{x^n}{x^n}&=1\\
x^{n-n}&=1\\
x^0&=1
\end{align}

Comment: Why can't it be $-\sqrt{x}$. Is it defined non- negative?

Comment: With regard to your point "mathematicians have tried defining something one way, then later developments revealed that the definition was not the right one, and it had to be revised". That sounds a bit disturbing, as if parts of math are "true until proven false"Is it still possible for us to make a discovery today which gives a different result for, say, $\sqrt e$, and cause us to revise the whole definition?

Comment: Maybe? The whole notion of what a number is has been revised several times so far.

Answer (score 6):

For $x\geq 0 $ and by definition $\sqrt x$ is the positive real $y$ such that $y^2=x$
and since 
$$\left(x^p\right)^q=x^{pq}$$
then for $p=\frac1 2$ and $q=2$ we see that $x^{1/2}=\sqrt x$