# If $x^a$ is $x$ multiplied $a$ times, then how does $x^{-1}$ make sense?

Tags: exponentiation

What is the meaning of $x$ raised to any non-positive value? We know that $x^{-a} = \dfrac{1}{x^a}$ and $x^0 = 1$, but where does that come from? What is the proof? Why is this true? What about $x$ raised to a fraction, like say $\frac{1}{3}$? *How do you multiply $x$ $\frac{1}{3}$ times?*

Comment: It is its inverse: $$0\neq x\in\Bbb R\implies x^{-1}:=\frac1x$$

Comment: I have edited the question. Everybody knows that.

Comment: For beginners: there is no proof. It is a definition. For more advanced students: by means of other things, like limits...but relying, again, on certain definitions.

Comment: Not a beginner here.

Comment: Then remember limits, logarithmic functions and etc.

Comment: To go from say $x^3$ to $x^2$, that is, to lose $1$ in the exponent, we have to divide by $x$. Therefore to go from $x^0$ to $x^{-1}$ we have to divide $x^0$ by $x$ which gives $1/x$.

Comment: How does (-1)x=-x make sense?

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278290) question.

Comment: Because i told you toooooo.

Answer (score 9):

From that definition, it doesn't make sense. It's what we mathematicians call a generalisation. The original definition of powers only allow natural numbers to be exponents.

However, one can ask "Is it possible to come up with a definition of $x^{-a}$ that plays well along with the old definition?" By which we mean that $x^{b+c}=x^bx^c$ and $(x^b)^c=x^{bc}$ still holds. And it turns out that there is exactly one definition that works.

In the same way you get $x^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]x$. Not because the old definition says so, but because it's the only thing it can be if we want it to work.

Answer (score 8):

We know that $x^{a+b}=x^ax^b$ since an $(a+b)$ amount of $x$'s is the same as an $a$ amount of $x$'s times a $b$ amount of $x$'s.

From this, we have

$$x^0=x^{a-a}=x^ax^{-a}$$

Thus, we have

$$x^{-a}=\frac{x^0}{x^a}$$

and once you show $x^0=1$, your done.

As for fractions, show that

$$x^{\frac ab}=y$$

For some value of $y$ which we are trying to solve for.

We see this is the same as

$$x^{\frac ab}=\underbrace{x\times x\times x\times\dots x}_{a/b?}=y$$

However, we see that by multiplying both sides on itself $b$ times, we have

$$\underbrace{x\times x\times x\times\dots x}_{a/b}=y\implies\underbrace{x\times x\times x\times\dots x}_{a}=y^b$$

and so,

$$\underbrace{x\times x\times x\times\dots x}_{a/b}=\sqrt[b]{\underbrace{x\times x\times x\times\dots x}_{a}}$$

> $$x^{\frac ab}=\sqrt[b]{x^a}$$