# Difference between $\sqrt x $(square root)and $x^\frac{1}{2}$(half power)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My teacher said that for $\sqrt{x}$ X must belong to integer whereas in $x^\frac{1}{2}$ X belong to entire complex plane.  Is there any source for that? How are $\sqrt{x}$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ actually defined?

Comment: That is ... wrong. $\sqrt x  \equiv x^{\frac 12}$ and both belong to the entire complex plane. Are you sure you haven't misunderstood your teacher?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is ${x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ the same as $\sqrt x $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537383/why-is-x-frac12-the-same-as-sqrt-x)

Comment: Now when I look back what he might mean is that $\frac{a}{b} \sqrt X $ has no meaning if a/b don't simplify to natural number. Which again opens a new question. Sigh.

Comment: @saketkumar no they are completely different questions.

Comment: Are you sure that you don’t mean _real number_ instead of “integer” or “natural number?” The value of $\sqrt2$ is neither, but it is a real number.

Comment: As an aside, whenever I see “My teacher said...” questions here, I always end up wondering why people don’t ask the _teacher_ to clarify the statement.

Comment: There is a reason for that. I don't want the teacher to make fun of me in front of whole class.  You are very lucky that you can ask your teacher a stupid question without hesitation. Not everyone is as lucky as you.( I mean no disrespect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between $\sqrt x$ and $x^{1/2}$.

However, for the second part of your question, sometimes $f=\sqrt{\cdot}$ is understood as a function, e.g. $f:\mathbb R_0^+\to\mathbb R_0^+$ or $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$. Sometimes (and more infrequently), however, it is understood as a relation. The latter is often needed in the complex plane, where there are multiple branches of the square root.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that without further specification, they both require that $x$ is a non-negative two number to be well-defined.

Ultimately, they are interchangeable. The difference is mainly about what you want to convey. For $\sqrt x$, the $\sqrt{\phantom x}$ part is usually quite fixed, while for $x^{1/2}$, the $^{1/2}$ part is very much something that can partake in any arithmetic that might happen. At least that's how I feel about them.

Comment: How is $\sqrt •$ fixed ? Can't we write $ \frac{a}{b} \sqrt x $.

Comment: @user654700 What do you mean by $\frac ab\sqrt x$? Do you mean $\sqrt[a/b]x$, the $\frac ab$th root of $x$? Sure, we can write that. That's not what I mean. What I mean is that when I write $\sqrt x$, I usually intend for it to stay as $\sqrt{\phantom x}$. I may change what's outside the root and what's inside the root, or the root might disappear, but I usually wouldn't change the root itself. If I intend for it to change, then I would use fractional exponents instead (for instance, I wouldn't write $\sqrt x\sqrt[3]x=\sqrt[6/5]x$, but instead go for $x^{1/2}x^{1/3}=x^{5/6}$).